# Problem connecting to my Database when setting up my first node

Tags: chainlink

When I try to execute this command:

cd ~/.chainlink-kovan && docker run -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-kovan:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink: local n

(I entered ut with my version of course)

I get this error:

[image]

The node and the database are both hosted on AWS.

This is my environment:

[image]

Comment: Hey! Could you please share the files again here, because they are not displayed correctly, just the description txt.

Comment: are you sure you have postgre running?

Comment: ....and use unix domain socket then

Comment: Can you remove your images and replace them with the actual text/code? It's too hard to search this without the actual text

Comment: And also add the error. I can't read it based on your image, and it's not searchable in its current state.

Answer (score 2):

the issue is related to the configuration of your postgresql server.

To connect to the database you need a specially created `USER` with a `PASSWORD`, which then locks this database by starting the Chainlink node. The **default** **`postgres`** `USER` and `DATABASE` will not work because it is used for administrative purposes. These credentials are then added to the environmental variable where you have the correct syntax:
`DATABASE_URL=postgresql://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$SERVER:5432/$DATABASE`

You can follow those steps to create the `USER` with credentials:

1. access the postgresql server/ host via `psql` command line interface:

```
psql --host=mypostgresql.c6c8mwvfdgv0.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432
```

2. Create the `USER` and grant all privileges:

```
CREATE USER youruser WITH PASSWORD 'yourpass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE yourdbname TO youruser;
```

Now you just need to change the `DATABASE_URL` configuration in your environmenal file (.env) and kill & restart the Chainlink node

In addition and in order to access the postgresql server hosted on AWS, you can have a look at the official documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.html